# Calling heightForRowAtIndexPath from within cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So, it seems that `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called before `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I'm currently using `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to calculate the height of each cell (they're variable heights, using a `UILabel` with varying amounts of text in it.

I'm puzzled as to exactly how I can set the cell's height correctly if the method that **sets** the height is called before the method that **calculates** it.

I've created a category of `NSString`, and another of `UILabel`, which working together make the `UILabel` the right size. The issue is that the `UITableViewCell` instances which contain those labels aren't being resized, so the labels hang over the end of each label, overlapping the ones beneath.

I know that what I need to do is make the height of the cell equal the height of the label, plus some extra margin space, but I'm puzzled as to how I can set the height before the label height has been calculated. Can I set the height someone without using `heightForRowAtIndexPath`? Or if not, could I calculate the height of the cell elsewhere? I'm currently using `indexPath.row` to make that happen, so doing it beforehand would be tricky. Here's the code my cellForRowAtIndexPath:

**cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    FQCustomCell *_customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"CustomCell"];
    if (_customCell == nil) {
        _customCell = [[FQCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier: @"CustomCell"];
    }

    _customCell.myLabel.text = [[_loadedNames objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] name];
    _customCell.myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"FontA" size: 15.0f];

    UIView *backView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
    backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _customCell.backgroundView = backView;

    _customCell.myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 265, 65);

    [_customCell.myLabel sizeToFitMultipleLines];
    return _customCell;
}
```

Comment: Starting with iOS 8 there you can also use automatically calculated dynamic row heights. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to calculate the height of the cell in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, something like

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *theText=[[_loadedNames objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] name];
    CGSize labelSize = [theText sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"FontA" size: 15.0f] constrainedToSize:kLabelFrameMaxSize];
    return kHeightWithoutLabel+labelSize.height;
}
```

You can set some constraints on the label size by setting `kLabelFrameMaxSize`

```
#define kLabelFrameMaxSize CGSizeMake(265.0, 200.0)
```

Then you return the height by adding a constant height with the variable label height.

Also, to be consistent, you should use the same methodology to set the frame in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` instead of using `sizeToFitMultipleLines`

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    FQCustomCell *_customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"CustomCell"];
    if (_customCell == nil) {
        _customCell = [[FQCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier: @"CustomCell"];
    }

    _customCell.myLabel.text = [[_loadedNames objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] name];
    _customCell.myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"FontA" size: 15.0f];

    UIView *backView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
    backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _customCell.backgroundView = backView;

    CGSize labelSize = [_customCell.myLabel.text sizeWithFont:_customCell.myLabel.font constrainedToSize:kLabelFrameMaxSize];
    _customCell.myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, labelSize.width, labelSize.height);

    return _customCell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should calculate the height of the cell in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method. It should be done without using any UILabel, just like `heightForRowAtIndexPath` implementation in JP Hribovsek's answer.

Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` do not set the frame of any subviews and do not call `sizeToFitMultipleLines` method of the label. Instead, implement `layoutSubviews` method of `FQCustomCell` such that the subview frames are set correctly for any possible bounds of the cell. You should't care about the text or font size in this method, just make sure the margins of the label are correct. If the height of the cell is calculated correctly in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method, the size of your labels will be just right.

Answer (score -2):

For every cell heightforRowAtIndexPath is called first and then CellForRowAtIndexPath . So you can calculate the height first and then fill up the data in CellForRowAtIndexPath for every cell.