# Passing the height of the cell from its own class to the UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have the cell, which is declared in its own class, so when I use cellForRowAtIndexPath - I create an instance of this class and assign the labels for the cell etc, but the height of the cell I need to calculate in this class too. So how can I pass the value of the height for heightForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: are you using custom cell .. ?

Comment: in storyboard it is a custom cell, yes

Answer (score 0):

Answer is here:

[Calling heightForRowAtIndexPath from within cellForRowAtIndexPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956189/calling-heightforrowatindexpath-from-within-cellforrowatindexpath)

Quick google search lead to this :)

Comment: Did this help you or not? Please let me know and mark accordingly!