# Change cell height by the content of the textView inside the cell

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uitableview

I have a Table View called `todoTableView` with cells that created by the user.
Each cell has Text View.
I want to change the height of the cell by the content of the Text View.
This is what I tried:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath:indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.bounds.size.height = cell.textView.bounds.size.height

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956189/calling-heightforrowatindexpath-from-within-cellforrowatindexpath).

Comment: @Irfan Yes.
Phoen1xUK - I don't know Objective-C

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Bound Your `textview` with `cell` from all sides using marginal constraints.(**Leading, Trailing, Top and Bottom constraints**)

[image]

- Disable textView Scrolling

In **viewDidLoad()** add the following.

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

This will make your cell size according to your textview content size.

Have a look at result :

[image]

You don't need to write **heightForRowAtIndexPath**.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work, maybe I'm not using marginal as right.
Can you tell me please how to do it specific?

Comment: Do you have the same case as above? If yes then select textview and set its leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints to zero with contentView of cell. Make sure you disable scrolling of textview. Try this and let me know if it help. thanks

Comment: Ok I have just done it and it still doesn't work.. the keeps writing but the cell height doesn't change

Comment: This feature is called self sizing table view. follow step by step one of the two links.
http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/
http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift. Both are in swift.

Comment: Update: When I said It doesn't work - my array had nothing in it, and I added content to it in the App while its running, In this case the cell height wasn't updated. But now I put content in the array before running the app and it changes! but still do not change while I change the content while running the app.

Comment: The issues you mention have nothing to do with self sizing cells. You should post a separate post about these.

Comment: This answer is awesome!.  tableView.estimatedRowHeight is necessary but increasing and decreasing it doesn't seem to affect the cell hight?

Comment: @fullMoon Its for the performance, we provide the average estimated height to minimize calculation, tableview will directly create cell with estimated height  and then increase or decrease cell height according to content

Answer (score -2):

[Irfan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32653118/8601760) didn't work for me.

It works after I go to Size Inspector and check "Automatic" for "Row Height".

Answer (score -3):

You should also implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat 
{
    return // Calculate your custom row height here.
}
```

Comment: What do I write after the return? I want it to be dynamic and not static.

Comment: You'll need to calculate the row height and this depends very much on exactly what you want to do. You can get the height based on the cell by retrieving it, cache it upon cell creation, or determine it by calculating the text height (by temporarily adding a view or through `sizeThatFits`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19049532/how-do-i-size-a-uitextview-to-its-content-on-ios-7 for more methods.

Comment: This solution is outdated and is computationaly more expensive than the canonical one. iOS 8 allows automatic cell sizing as suggested by @Irfan.

Comment: If you don't need iOS 7 then that is absolutely right. I don't see a version mentioned.