# calculation of cell height dynamically

Tags: ios

I have a `tableview` in which there is a `uilabel` inside the cell. `label` takes variable height on the basis of text.My codes are below

```
- (CGFloat)getLabelHeight:(UILabel*)label
{
  CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(label.frame.size.width-10, 1000.0f);      
  CGSize size;

  NSStringDrawingContext *context = [[NSStringDrawingContext alloc] init];
  CGSize boundingBox = [label.text boundingRectWithSize:constraint
                                              options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:label.font}
                                              context:context].size;

  size = CGSizeMake(ceil(boundingBox.width), ceil(boundingBox.height));

  return size.height;
}
```

but setting `constraint` is difficult one. AnyOne knows the easiest way to calculate the height of cell dynamically and correct way of setting constraint.

Comment: This article is worth reading:  http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift

Comment: @jinnie if possible can you please send me sample code project I'll try to solve your problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32652612/change-cell-height-by-the-content-of-the-textview-inside-the-cell/32653118#32653118

This is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `autolayout` then it will be easiest.Just add top,left,right and botton constraints for your `UILabel`, set `numberofLines` to 0 and line break mode to wordWrap. and in your `heightForRow` method pass `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

**P.S.** If there is only label in your cell then instead of using custom  cell , use `UITableViewCell` and use its text label.You then won't have to manage any constraints.