# Prevent "....." when displaying json data into tableview

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I am trying to show josn data and this happens

How can i prevent the ... from appering and show the full text?

Here is code

Here is Pic to show what is the problem
[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/td6Vp.png)

As you can see there is the "..." and does not show full text

Any fix for this?

Thanks

```
    [{"url":"","description":"rferferferferferferferferferferferferferferferferfreferferferferferferferferfeerfeferferferf"},
{"url":"","description":"Image Description"},
{"url":"","description":"Image Description"},
{"url":"","description":"Image Descriprffttion"},
{"url":"","description":"Image Descriptijijion"},
{"url":"","description":"Image Description"},

{"url":"","description":"techavindu"},
{"url":"","description":"Image Description"},
{"url":"","description":"Imagesdaasdsd Description"},
{"url":"","description":"Image Descriprffttion"},
{"url":"","description":"Image Descriptijijion"},
{"url":"","description":"Image Dyubuyuubububububububuescription"},

{"url":"","description":"techavindu"},
{"url":"","description":"Image Description"},
{"url":"","description":"Imagesdaasdsd Description"},
{"url":"","description":"Image Descriprffttion"},
{"url":"","description":"Image Descriptijijion"},





]

 var json_data_url = "http://aliectronics.com.au/json_table_view_images%20(1).json"


    var isProgressShowing = true;

    var TableData:Array< datastruct > = Array < datastruct >()

    enum ErrorHandler:ErrorType
    {
        case ErrorFetchingResults
    }


    struct datastruct
    {

        var description:String?


        init(add: NSDictionary)
        {

            description = add["description"] as? String



        }

    }

    @IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = color125



        tableview.dataSource = self
        tableview.delegate = self

        get_data_from_url(json_data_url)
    }




    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Refresh", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "refreshTapped");
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;
    }



    func refreshTapped() {
        addProgressIndicator(isProgressShowing);
        get_data_from_url(json_data_url)

    }

    func addProgressIndicator(show : Bool) {
        isProgressShowing = !show;
        if(show) {
            let myActivityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray)
            myActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
            let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: myActivityIndicator)
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem




        } else {
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;




        }




    }




    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        let data = TableData[indexPath.row]


        cell.textLabel?.text = data.description



        return cell

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return TableData.count
    }







    func get_data_from_url(url:String)
    {


        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: url)!
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData


        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            (
            let data, let response, let error) in

            guard let _:NSData = data, let _:NSURLResponse = response where error == nil else {
                print("error")
                return
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.extract_json(data!)
                return
            })

        }
        addProgressIndicator(!isProgressShowing);
        task.resume()



    }


    func extract_json(jsonData:NSData)
    {
        let json: AnyObject?
        do {
            json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: [])
        } catch {
            json = nil
            return
        }

        if let list = json as? NSArray
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < list.count ; i++ )
            {
                if let data_block = list[i] as? NSDictionary
                {

                    TableData.append(datastruct(add: data_block))
                }
            }


            do_table_refresh()

        }


    }




    func do_table_refresh()


    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.tableview.reloadData()



            return
        })
    }









}
```

Comment: Are you looking for the text to wrap onto the next line?

Comment: Please use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem.  Avoid including code that is clearly unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using auto dimension for the cell of tableview. Kindly follow this url. He have mention about the textview. you can do  same with label.

[Change height of textview according to content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32652612/change-cell-height-by-the-content-of-the-textview-inside-the-cell/32653118#32653118)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your text is in a `UILabel`, you can use `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` along the lines of:

```
myLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Have a look at the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth). Given that your using a UITableViewCell, you would do something like:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let data = TableData[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = data.description
    cell.textLabel!.minimumFontSize = 8
    cell.textLabel!.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

    return cell
}
```

I have also set the minimum font size above, so it doesn't get so small you can't see it.

Comment: its in table view cell

Comment: do you want full project?

Comment: Assuming it's a basic table view cell, then you should be able to set that property on its textLabel property, as it is a UILabel.

Comment: i am new how do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can change number of lines of textLabel to be displayed on tableview cell like given below. 
By setting it to "0" it'll display full text, no meter how long it is. And if you want fix lines and after that wrap the content. You can set digits other then 0.

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    ....
    }
```