# how to give constraints for uilabel and uitextview in custom table cell by programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

Below mentioned link where  my actual simulator screenshot . I have a query of how to adjust the `label`(brown colour) and `textview` (black colour) based upon the content from `JSON`, i did it on the static part of `auto layout` for `UILabel` and `textview` , how to code  the `constraints`  for `UILabel` and `textview` in `custom cell`  such that it adjusted dynamically

[image]

awaiting for your awesome responses!!

Comment: I think you upload image url deleted, one more time upload your screenshots

Comment: [http://i.stack.imgur.com/rQfwn.png]

Comment: Use dynamic self sizing of uitableview: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32653118/4272498

Answer (score 0):

You should work with `Self-Sizing Table View Cells`.

Set tableview Row height and estimated row height like,

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 85.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

It must require proper autolayout when set height as `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

As [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html) states,

> To define the cell’s height, you need an unbroken chain of constraints and views (with defined heights) to fill the area between the content view’s top edge and its bottom edge. If your views have intrinsic content heights, the system uses those values. If not, you must add the appropriate height constraints, either to the views or to the content view itself.

You need to set unbroken chain of constraints that means first object must have top and last must have bottom and if there is only one object in cell then it must have both top and bottom.

You can refer [Appcoda's tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/) for more details.

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

I am giving my colors dynamically

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:brownColor];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:whiteColor];
```