# What is best text container for multiline text in IOS

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin.ios

I try to make Android/IOS app with chat in Visual Studio with Xamarin. And I have a problem with chat baloons.  For Android it's ok, I use Text View as message container. But in IOS I met a problem - If I use TextView I got only white rectangles. To implement list of messages I use UITableView with this code

```
public override void ViewDidLoad(){
  _chatsMessagesListAdapter = new MessagesTableSourceClass(chatData._messages);
  messagesList.Source = _chatsMessagesListAdapter;
}

public class MessagesTableSourceClass : UITableViewSource
    {
        readonly List<MessageData> _dataList;
        public MessagesTableSourceClass(List<MessageData> dataList)
        {
            _dataList = dataList;
        }
        public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
        {
            return _dataList.Count;
        }
        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
OwnerMessageTableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(MessageTableViewCell.Key) as OwnerMessageTableViewCell ?? OwnerMessageTableViewCell.Create();
cell.BindData(_dataList[indexPath.Row]._message, _dataList[indexPath.Row]._image);
return cell;
        }
        public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, true);
        }
        public override UIView GetViewForFooter(UITableView tableView, nint section)
        {
            return new UIView();
        }
    }
```

**OwnerMessageTableViewCell.xib** is simple structure TableViewCell -> View -> TextView

But in result TableView messagesList is shown like white rectangle.
Can anybody help me with this problem?

**UPDATED**
Here the implementation of OwnerMessageTableViewCell

```
public partial class OwnerMessageTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
    {
        public static readonly UINib Nib = UINib.FromName("OwnerMessageTableViewCell", NSBundle.MainBundle);
        public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString("OwnerMessageTableViewCell");
        public OwnerMessageTableViewCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }
        public static OwnerMessageTableViewCell Create()
        {
            return (OwnerMessageTableViewCell)Nib.Instantiate(null, null)[0];
        }
        internal void BindData(string message, UIImage avatar)
        {
            messageIcon.Image = avatar;
            workerIcon.Hidden = false;
            messageText.Text = message;
        }
    }
```

Here xib file content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="13529" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="13527"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner"/>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" id="252" customClass="OwnerMessageTableViewCell" rowHeight="44">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="240" height="44"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
            <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="252" id="253">
                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="240" height="43"/>
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                <subviews>
                    <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" id="280" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" fixedFrame="YES" clipsSubviews="YES" image="Images/worker_icon.png">
                        <rect key="frame" x="190" y="0.0" width="50" height="50"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMinX="YES" flexibleMinY="YES"/>
                        <userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
                            <userDefinedRuntimeAttribute keyPath="layer.cornerRadius" type="number">
                                <real key="value" value="25"/>
                            </userDefinedRuntimeAttribute>
                        </userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
                    </imageView>
                    <textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" textAlignment="justified" id="307" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" fixedFrame="YES" text="Message Text here..." editable="NO" selectable="NO">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="182" height="50"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" colorSpace="calibratedRGB" red="0.094117647058823528" green="0.31372549019607843" blue="0.63921568627450975" alpha="1"/>
                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                        <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocapitalizationType="sentences"/>
                        <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                        <inset key="scrollIndicatorInsets" minX="5" minY="5" maxX="5" maxY="5"/>
                        <userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
                            <userDefinedRuntimeAttribute keyPath="layer.cornerRadius" type="number">
                                <real key="value" value="15"/>
                            </userDefinedRuntimeAttribute>
                        </userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
                    </textView>
                    <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" id="384" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" fixedFrame="YES" image="Images/worker_icon.png">
                        <rect key="frame" x="220" y="30" width="20" height="20"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                    </imageView>
                </subviews>
            </tableViewCellContentView>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-132.5" y="-317"/>
            <connections>
                <outlet property="messageIcon" destination="280" id="name-outlet-280"/>
                <outlet property="messageText" destination="307" id="name-outlet-307"/>
                <outlet property="workerIcon" destination="384" id="name-outlet-384"/>
            </connections>
            <color key="backgroundColor" colorSpace="calibratedRGB" red="0.54117647058823526" green="0.54117647058823526" blue="0.54117647058823526" alpha="1"/>
        </tableViewCell>
    </objects>
    <resources>
        <image name="chat_bg.jpg" width="414" height="648"/>
    </resources>
</document>
```

**UPDATED**

Here a screens of VS designer window

[image: design of tableviewcell];

[image: properties];

[image: layout];

Comment: I can't see you set the rowHeight , and how you set the textView in your cell, did you give it a frame or constrain?

Comment: @ColeXia I added xib file content. Look at it, please.

Comment: @ColeXia I added some screens. I think it all about TextView, because I use same model for sliding menu (but use Label instead TextView), and it works without problem.

Comment: refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32652612/change-cell-height-by-the-content-of-the-textview-inside-the-cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust the cell height depending on the text .

There are several solutions in native ios, I recommend you to have a look at [Auto-Sizing Row Height](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/controls/tables/autosizing-row-height/).

Steps:

1. modify the `Content Hugging Priority` and `Content Compression Resistance Priority` on the `UITextView` to operate the cell layout
2. set `Estimated RowHeight` to enable the Auto-Resizing.

Comment: Thank you. That's just what I need. Now all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Create a uiview that will act as the container for the text view. Add the textview inside the uiview. Then set the colour of the text view to transparent. Set the constraints so that the text view is positioned correctly inside the uiview. Apply a corner radius to the uiview to make it appear like a bubble. You will need to adjust the height of the cell depending on the containing text.

Comment: I do right like this except last part - I don't know how to adjust the height of the cell depending on the containing text.